# Shiny Reactive materialSwitch dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinywidgets

I am trying to use a `materialSwitch` from `shinyWidgets` to control a dplyr filter that catches text in a certain column using `grepl`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "status",
      label = "Status:",
      choices = sort(unique(df$STATUS)),
      selected = unique(df$STATUS))
  
    materialSwitch(
       inputId = "switch",
       label = "TEXT", 
        value = FALSE,
       status = "primary"
    )

    filtered_data <-
        reactive ({
          req(input$status,
              input$switch)
          
          ready_for_reg %>% 
            filter(STATUS %in% input$status) %>%  
            filter(if(input$switch == TRUE) grepl("TEST",COL1) else TRUE )
           
    
        })

 DT::renderDataTable(datatable(filtered_data())
```

This code works when the switch is clicked and set to TRUE. However when it is in the default status of FALSE the table is not showing up at all. How can I make sure the `filtered_date()` variable shows all data when the button is not clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req(FALSE)` stops the event so `req(input$status,input$switch)` stops the event when the switch is FALSE.

This is why you don't have no result.

To fix it change to `req(input$status)`